# expdp fails with error ORA-31626 without any details on a full export

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, expdp

I am exporting a complete database (`full=y`) on oracle 11gR2 on Linux, and always get this error. There are no other messages, so the problem is not about timeout or permissions as shown elsewhere. This is what is printed on the terminal:

```
$ expdp parfile=20230503021002_1.par
Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mer Mag 3 12:46:48 2023
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
Connesso a: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and OLAP options
ORA-31626: il job non esiste
```

The complete parfile is:

```
userid=system/*****
directory=expdp_dir
dumpfile=20230503021002_1_%U.dmp
logfile=20230503021002_1.log
job_name=expdp_full_1_20230503021002
full=Y
content=all
parallel=2
flashback_time="to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"
```

`expdp` completes in about 21 seconds and leave table `system.EXPDP_FULL_1_20230503021002` with 1987 records. Nothing is added to the alert log beside

```
Wed May 03 12:46:49 2023
DM00 started with pid=70, OS id=27939, job SYSTEM.EXPDP_FULL_1_20230503021002
```

only one dump file is created and it is 4096 bytes long.

How may I better investigate the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you specifying a `flashback_time` of `sysdate`? What happens if you don't specify `flashback_time`?

Have you seen this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=getting-ora-31626-job-does-not-exist-and-ora-06512-from-my-export-data-pump-job

If you're using `system` to run the export, it *should* have the necessary privileges, so:

> make sure
>
> - aq_tm_processes is greater than zero
> - streams_pool_size is greater than zero
>
> since datapump uses these facilities to work

If there are no other errors and nothing else works, contact Oracle Support. If you have a My Oracle Support account already, check this out: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1970322_1.html

Comment: `aq_tm_processes` is 1, `streams_pool_size` is 0. But, `select component, current_size/1048576 curr_size, max_size/1048576 max_size from v$sga_dynamic_components where component='streams pool';` shows a value of 48 (megabytes), so maybe this value is automatic. Removing the flashback_time parameter does not change the result.

Comment: Changing value to `streams_pool_size` fails with ar error about low memory. I am going to increase the SGA but I cannot restart the instance right now. I'll keep you posted. Thank you. @pmdba

Comment: Well, resizing the SGA from 4 to 8Gb solved the problem. I did not had to change any other parameters. In fact `streams_pool_size` seems to be auto tuned. Thank you for pointing me to this direction @pmdba .

Answer (score 0):

Well, resizing the SGA from 4 to 8Gb solved the problem. I did not had to change any other parameters. In fact streams_pool_size seems to be auto tuned. Thank you for pointing me to this direction @pmdba .